Proof of Newton-Kantorovich theorem, Wikipedia version
Context
I have recently been researching the Newton-Kantorovich theorem after wondering about convergence criteria for the Newton-Raphson method in numerical analysis, as it seems to be the most precise one I could find. My goal is to formalize its proof in the Lean 4 programming language and theorem prover for the case of real numbers. However, there are numerous formulations of this statement. The original statement by L. V. Kantorovich in 1948 used $3$ bounding constants, as shown in [On the Newton-Kantorovich Theorem] by PHILIPPE G. CIARLET and CRISTINEL MARDARE:

Theorem 3 (The Classical Newton-Kantorovich Theorem "with Three
Constants"). Let there be given two Banach spaces $X$ and $Y$, an open
subset $\Omega$ of $X$, a point $x_0 \in \Omega$, and a mapping $f \in
 C^1(\Omega; Y)$ such that $f'(x_0) \in \mathcal{L}(X; Y)$ is
one-to-one and onto, so that $f'(x_0)^{-1} \in \mathcal{L}(Y; X)$ (by
Banach open mapping theorem). Assume that
there exist three constants $\lambda, \mu, \nu$ such that
$$ 0 < \lambda \mu \nu \leq \frac{1}{2} \quad \text{and} \quad B(x_0;
r) \subset \Omega, \quad \text{where} \quad r := \frac{1}{\mu \nu}, $$
$$ \|f'(x_0)^{-1} f(x_0)\| \leq \lambda, \quad
\|f'(x_0)^{-1}\|_{\mathcal{L}(Y; X)} \leq \mu, $$
$$ \|f'(\tilde{x}) - f'(x)\|_{\mathcal{L}(X; Y)} \leq \nu \|\tilde{x}
- x\| \quad \text{for all} \quad \tilde{x}, x \in B(x_0; r). $$
Then $f'(x) \in \mathcal{L}(X; Y)$ is one-to-one and onto and
$f'(x)^{-1} \in \mathcal{L}(Y; X)$ at each $x \in B(x_0; r)$, the
sequence $(x_k)_{k=0}^{\infty}$ defined by
$$ x_{k+1} = x_k - f'(x_k)^{-1} f(x_k), \quad k \geq 0, $$
is contained in the ball $B(x_0; r_-)$, where
$$ r_- := \frac{1 - \sqrt{1 - 2 \lambda \mu \nu}}{\mu \nu} \leq r, $$
and converges to a zero $a \in B(x_0; r_-)$ of $f$. Besides, for each
$k \geq 0$,
$$ \|x_k - a\| \leq \frac{r}{2^k} \left( \frac{r_-}{r} \right)^{2^k}
\quad \text{if} \quad \lambda \mu \nu < \frac{1}{2}, \quad \text{or}
\quad \|x_k - a\| \leq \frac{r}{2^k} \quad \text{if} \quad \lambda \mu
\nu = \frac{1}{2}. $$
If $\lambda \mu \nu < \frac{1}{2}$, assume in addition that
$$ B(x_0; r_+) \subset \Omega, \quad \text{where} \quad r_+ := \frac{1
+ \sqrt{1 - 2 \lambda \mu \nu}}{\mu \nu}, $$
$$ \|f'(\tilde{x}) - f'(x)\|_{\mathcal{L}(X; Y)} \leq \nu \|\tilde{x}
- x\| \quad \text{for all} \quad \tilde{x}, x \in B(x_0; r_+). $$
Then, the point $a \in B(x_0; r_-)$ is the only zero of $f$ in $B(x_0;
r_+)$. If $\lambda \mu \nu = \frac{1}{2}$ (in which case $r_- = r =
r_+$), assume in addition that
$$ \overline{B(x_0; r)} \subset \Omega. $$
Then, the point $a \in \overline{B(x_0; r)}$ is the only zero of $f$
in $\overline{B(x_0; r)}$.

References such as Kantorovich's Theorem on Newton's Method by O. P. Ferreira, B. F. Svaiter and On the Newton–Kantorovich hypothesis for solving equations by Ioannis K. Argyros present the theorem using $2$ bounding constants:

Let $X$, $Y$ be Banach spaces, $C\subseteq X$
and $F:{C}\to Y$ a continuous function, continuously
differentiable on $\mathrm{int}(C)$. Take $x_0\in \mathrm{int}(C)$,
$L,\, b>0$ and suppose that

$F '(x_0)$ is non-singular
$\|F'(x_0)^{-1}\left[ F'(y)-F'(x)\right]\| \leq L\|x-y\|$ for any $x,y\in C$
$\|F'(x_0)^{-1}F(x_0)\|\leq b$
$2bL\leq 1$.
Define
$$t_*:=\frac{1-\sqrt{1-2bL}}{L},\qquad
t_{**}:=\frac{1+\sqrt{1-2bL}}{L}. $$
If $B[x_0,t_*]\subset C $,
then  the sequences $\{x_k\}$ generated by Newton's Method for
solving $F(x)=0$ with starting point $x_0$,
\begin{equation} \label{ns.KT} 
x_{k+1} ={x_k}-F'(x_k) ^{-1}F(x_k), \qquad k=0,1,\cdots, 
  \end{equation}
is well defined, is contained in $B(x_0, t_*)$, converges to a
point $x_*\in B[x_0,t_*]$ which is the unique zero of $F$ in
$B[x_0,t_*]$ and
\begin{equation}
\label{eq:q.conv.x}
\|x_*-x_{k+1}\|\leq \frac{1}{2} \|x_*-x_k \|, \qquad
k=0,1,\,\cdots. 
  \end{equation}
Moreover, if assumption $4$ holds as an strict inequality, i.e.
$2bL<1$, then
\begin{equation} \label{eq:q2}
 \|x_*-x_{k+1}\|\leq\frac{1-\theta^{2^k}}{1+\theta^{2^k}}
 \frac{ L}{2\sqrt{1-2bL}}\|x_*-x_k\|^2\leq
 \frac{ L}{2\sqrt{1-2bL}}\|x_*-x_k\|^2, \quad k=0,1,\cdots, 
   \end{equation}
where $\theta:=t_*/t_{**}<1$, and $x_*$ is the
unique zero of $F$ in $B[x_0,\rho]$ for any $\rho$ such that
$$ t_*\leq\rho<t_{**},\qquad B[x_0,\rho]\subset C.$$


On the other hand, Wikipedia states a much more simple and powerful version of the statement for the case of $\mathbb{R}^n$, that only requires the Lipschitz constant of the derivative in a ball (or an absolute bound on the second derivative if it exists).

Let $X \subset \mathbb{R}^n$ be open, $F: X \to \mathbb{R}^n$ differentiable with locally Lipschitz continuous Jacobian $F'(x)$. For $x \in X$, there exists an open $U \subset X$ containing $x$ and $L > 0$ such that $\forall x, y \in U$:
$$\|F'(x) - F'(y)\| \leq L \|x - y\|$$
$$\|F'(x)(v) - F'(y)(v)\| \leq L \|x - y\| \|v\|$$ for all $v \in \mathbb{R}^n$.
Choose $x_0 \in X$. Assume $F'(x_0)$ invertible, and define $$h_0 = -F'(x_0)^{-1}F(x_0)$$
$$x_1 = x_0 + h_0$$
Let $M$ be the Lipschitz constant for $F'$ over the ball $B(x_1, \|h_0\|) \subset X$.
Then, construct sequences $(x_k)_k$, $(h_k)_k$, $(\alpha_k)_k$:
$$h_k = -F'(x_k)^{-1}F(x_k)$$
$$\alpha_k = M \|F'(x_k)^{-1}\| \|h_k\|$$
$$x_{k+1} = x_k + h_k$$
Statement: If $\alpha_0 \leq \frac{1}{2}$, then:

There exists a solution $x^*$ of $F(x^*) = 0$ in $\bar{B}(x_1, \|h_0\|)$
Newton iteration from $x_0$ converges to $x^*$ with at least linear order.


Question
What is the proof for the statement of the theorem on Wikipedia? I searched around but wasn't able to find it. The closest thing available was this answer by Lutz Lehmann 10 years ago, and it seems like the links have gone down.

Where did you find this third version? The current en:Kantorovich theorem page shows the first version. If you go down to the last paragraph you will find a link to Hubbard/Hubbard where the sample text on Newton-Kantorovich contains the last version, with some short hint towards the proof strategy. I might remember wrong, but I think to remember that the main difference to the stronger theorems is that the bound on the inverse of the Jacobian uses a weaker inequality with a shorter proof (which is not contained in the remarks in the book).

I see that de:Wikipedia still has the third version and the combination of first and second version on the talk page. The proof sketch for the third version is more complete than in the book. I did not include the quadratic convergence explicitly, it follows from $\alpha_{k+1}\le 2\alpha_k^2$.

I took it from the English Wikipedia page: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kantorovich_theorem. I'm not sure what you mean that it shows the first version, it shows the $\mathbb{R}^n$ version for me.

For the Newton-Kantorovich theorem it makes formally no difference if in finite dimension or in Banach space. Of course, the Jacobian being bounded and the inverse of it too are much more restrictive conditions in Banach space than just excluding singular matrices in finite dimension.

Oh. Well, I pretty much took it as is, just with some rearranging. If there is a proof with that condition I'd be happy as well.
